# Как сделать картинку "прозрачной", чтобы стала призраком

Tags: html, css

У меня есть верхний подвал, так же кнопки. Когда я картинку допустим перемещаю `margin-left: 25%;` то кнопки съезжают вниз, так же `z-index:` на картинку не работает. Может я конечно что то и упустил, но об этом статей не видал. Кнопку хочу сделать `margin-left: 30%`. Помогите пожалуйста.

```css
.top {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

button {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 3px solid #FF0000;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-style: italic;
}

button::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 0.85em 0.75em;
  display: block;
}

button[class^="grow"]::after {
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

button.grow_ellipse::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  top: -150%;
  bottom: -150%;
  line-height: 8.34em;
  transform: scale(0, 0);
}

button.grow_ellipse:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.top-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 60px;
  animation: poyavleniye 2s ease-out 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <img src="../Lib/Img/General/top.png" alt="" class="top-img">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#"><button class="grow_ellipse">1</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="grow_ellipse">1</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="grow_ellipse">1</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что простите? И где `@keyframes`?

Comment: Я делал кнопку по примеру, я в кнопках только разбираюсь

Comment: Я так понимаю речь идёт о эффекте появления "круга" внутри кнопки `button`? И разбираться нужно в вёрстке, а не в кнопках.. Так сказать в этом взаимосвязь есть.

Comment: Нет, я когда картинку делаю на ```margin-left: 25%```, то кнопки падают вниз, а я хочу чтобы оставались на уровне с картинкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно Вас понял, вы хотите расположить картинку и кнопки в "одной плоскости" с чёрным фоном.
Для этого в идеале использовать [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
.top {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px;
}

.top-img {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 60px;
  animation: poyavleniye 2s ease-out 1;
}

.top .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: auto;
}

button {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 3px solid #FF0000;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-style: italic;
  z-index: 1;
}

button::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 0.85em 0.75em;
  display: block;
}

button[class^="grow"]::after {
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

button.grow_ellipse::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  top: -150%;
  bottom: -150%;
  line-height: 8.34em;
  transform: scale(0, 0);
}

button.grow_ellipse:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <img src="../Lib/Img/General/top.png" alt="" class="top-img">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#"><button class="grow_ellipse">1</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="grow_ellipse">1</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="grow_ellipse">1</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если же нет, то будьте добры, зарисуйте в том же Paint как хотите отобразить элементы и выложите, допустим на [Imgur](https://imgur.com/)

Comment: Спасибо, а почему у меня пропала анимация при наведении?

Comment: `button::after` из-за `z-index: -1` ушёл за чёрный блок, устранил проблему добавлением `z-index: 1;`